# Hole-Filling Filter in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a basic implementation of hole-filling filter as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // please note that the depthImg is (720 x 576) 8UC1
    // let's make a smaller one for testing
    uchar flatten[6 * 8] = { 140, 185,  48, 235, 201, 192, 131,  57,
                              55,  87,  82,   0,   6, 201,   0,  38,
                               6, 239,  82, 142,  46,  33, 172,  72,
                             133,   0, 232, 226,  66,  59,  10, 204,
                             214, 123, 202, 100,   0,  32,   6, 147,
                             105, 191,  50,  21,  87, 117, 118, 244};

    cv::Mat depthImg = cv::Mat(6, 8, CV_8UC1, flatten);

    // please ignore the border pixels in this case
    for (int i = 1; i < depthImg.cols - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < depthImg.rows - 1; j++) {
            unsigned short sumNonZeroAdjs = 0;
            uchar countNonZeroAdjs = 0;
            if (depthImg.at<uchar>(j, i) == 0) {
                uchar iMinus1 = depthImg.at<uchar>(j, i - 1);
                uchar  iPlus1 = depthImg.at<uchar>(j, i + 1);
                uchar jMinus1 = depthImg.at<uchar>(j - 1, i);
                uchar  jPlus1 = depthImg.at<uchar>(j + 1, i);
                if (iMinus1 != 0) {
                    sumNonZeroAdjs += iMinus1;
                    countNonZeroAdjs++;
                }
                if (iPlus1 != 0) {
                    sumNonZeroAdjs += iPlus1;
                    countNonZeroAdjs++;
                }
                if (jMinus1 != 0) {
                    sumNonZeroAdjs += jMinus1;
                    countNonZeroAdjs++;
                }
                if (jPlus1 != 0) {
                    sumNonZeroAdjs += jPlus1;
                    countNonZeroAdjs++;
                }
                depthImg.at<uchar>(j, i) = sumNonZeroAdjs / countNonZeroAdjs;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << depthImg << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
// prints the following:
[140, 185, 48, 235, 201, 192, 131, 57;
  55, 87, 82, 116, 6, 201, 135, 38;
  6, 239, 82, 142, 46, 33, 172, 72;
  133, 181, 232, 226, 66, 59, 10, 204;
  214, 123, 202, 100, 71, 32, 6, 147;
  105, 191, 50, 21, 87, 117, 118, 244]
```

The above filter computes an average of adjacent pixels to fill the 0 pixels. The output from this implementation is satisfactory. However, as we can see, the above prototype is not elegant and painfully slow.

**I am looking for a similar logic (using adjacent pixels to fill 0 pixels) but faster (execution time) hole-filling filter inbuilt in OpenCV**

PS: I am using OpenCV v4.2.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

### Update 1

Based on the suggestions, I designed pointer style access. Complete code is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void inPlaceHoleFillingExceptBorderPtrStyle(cv::Mat& img) {
  typedef uchar T;
  T* ptr = img.data;
  size_t elemStep = img.step / sizeof(T);

  for (int i = 1; i < img.rows - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < img.cols - 1; j++) {
      T& curr = ptr[i * elemStep + j];
      if (curr != 0) {
        continue;
      }

      ushort sumNonZeroAdjs = 0;
      uchar countNonZeroAdjs = 0;
      T iM1 = ptr[(i - 1) * elemStep + j];
      T iP1 = ptr[(i + 1) * elemStep + j];
      T jM1 = ptr[i * elemStep + (j - 1)];
      T jP1 = ptr[i * elemStep + (j + 1)];

      if (iM1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += iM1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (iP1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += iP1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (jM1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += jM1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (jP1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += jP1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (countNonZeroAdjs > 0) {
        curr = sumNonZeroAdjs / countNonZeroAdjs;
      }
    }
  }
}

void inPlaceHoleFillingExceptBorder(cv::Mat& img) {
  typedef uchar T;

  for (int i = 1; i < img.cols - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < img.rows - 1; j++) {
      ushort sumNonZeroAdjs = 0;
      uchar countNonZeroAdjs = 0;
      if (img.at<T>(j, i) != 0) {
        continue;
      }

      T iM1 = img.at<T>(j, i - 1);
      T iP1 = img.at<T>(j, i + 1);
      T jM1 = img.at<T>(j - 1, i);
      T jP1 = img.at<T>(j + 1, i);

      if (iM1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += iM1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (iP1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += iP1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (jM1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += jM1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (jP1 != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += jP1;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (countNonZeroAdjs > 0) {
        img.at<T>(j, i) = sumNonZeroAdjs / countNonZeroAdjs;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // please note that the img is (720 x 576) 8UC1
  // let's make a smaller one for testing
  // clang-format off
  uchar flatten[6 * 8] = { 140, 185,  48, 235, 201, 192, 131,  57,
                            55,  87,  82,   0,   6, 201,   0,  38,
                             6, 239,  82, 142,  46,  33, 172,  72,
                           133,   0, 232, 226,  66,  59,  10, 204,
                           214, 123, 202, 100,   0,  32,   6, 147,
                           105, 191,  50,  21,  87, 117, 118, 244};
  // clang-format on

  cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(6, 8, CV_8UC1, flatten);
  cv::Mat img1 = img.clone();
  cv::Mat img2 = img.clone();

  inPlaceHoleFillingExceptBorderPtrStyle(img1);
  inPlaceHoleFillingExceptBorder(img2);

  return 0;
}

/*** expected output
[140, 185,  48, 235, 201, 192, 131, 57;
  55,  87,  82, 116,  6,  201, 135, 38;
   6, 239,  82, 142, 46,   33, 172, 72;
 133, 181, 232, 226, 66,   59,  10, 204;
 214, 123, 202, 100, 71,   32,   6, 147;
 105, 191,  50,  21, 87,  117, 118, 244]
***/
```

### Update 2

Based on the suggestion, the point style code is further improved as shown below:

```
void inPlaceHoleFillingExceptBorderImpv(cv::Mat& img) {
  typedef uchar T;
  size_t elemStep = img.step1();
  const size_t margin = 1;

  for (size_t i = margin; i < img.rows - margin; ++i) {
    T* ptr = img.data + i * elemStep;
    for (size_t j = margin; j < img.cols - margin; ++j, ++ptr) {
      T& curr = ptr[margin];
      if (curr != 0) {
        continue;
      }

      T& north = ptr[margin - elemStep];
      T& south = ptr[margin + elemStep];
      T&  east = ptr[margin + 1];
      T&  west = ptr[margin - 1];

      ushort  sumNonZeroAdjs = 0;
      uchar countNonZeroAdjs = 0;
      if (north != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += north;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (south != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += south;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (east != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += east;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (west != 0) {
        sumNonZeroAdjs += west;
        countNonZeroAdjs++;
      }
      if (countNonZeroAdjs > 0) {
        curr = sumNonZeroAdjs / countNonZeroAdjs;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay! If writing the above snippet to C++ makes you happy, I am gonna do it soon. Sorry for the inconvenience. Please wait.

Comment: @enhzflep: I have added CPP code with the same concept. Please have a look. Clearly, it does not look good to iterate over an image like this. Not sure if [inpainting](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html) can help though.

Comment: “dirty hole-fillig filter”?

Comment: First of all, there is nothing wrong with iterating over pixels. This is how you implement filters. You could speed up the code by not using `depthImg.at<uchar>(j, i)`; instead, get a pointer to the first pixel, and the `s=step1()`, then access pixels through the pointer; the neighbors are at `p+1, p-1, p+s, p-s`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Sorry for confusion. I updated the question. By saying dirty, I was referring to my implementation (coding style). Thank you for suggesting to use pointers for faster access.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I have added the pointer style access in the above post. Please see "Update" section. I am not familiar with `s = step1()`. Would you mind elaborating a bit more, please?

Comment: `img.step1()` is the step size in samples rather than bytes, which you need to do pointer arithmetic. Your sample is one byte, so it doesn’t matter in this case, but you should use it to write generic code. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a0066c8eee40c1706395b1e57f00e0857

Comment: Looking at your code now. `img.step / sizeof(T)` is the same as `img.step1()`, so that’s OK. Inside the loop over rows, do `T* ptr = img.data + i * elemStep;`, the inner loop then is `for (int j = 1; j < img.cols - 1; ++j, ++ptr)`, then access the values with `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, `ptr[elemStep]`, etc. This avoids the repeated computation of a multiplication. Other than that, you’re not going to get more efficient code than that. Well done!

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thank you very much. With little bit of tweaks, I could implement your suggestions. Please see update #2 in the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/) advised a fantastic kernel-based approach. Unfortunately, the result is not matching with the expected output.

Therefore, based on various comments from [@CrisLuengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782), I managed to design time efficient version of the filter, as shown below:

```
void inPlaceHoleFillingExceptBorderFast(cv::Mat& img) {
  typedef uchar T;
  const size_t elemStep = img.step1();
  const size_t margin = 1;

  for (size_t i = margin; i < img.rows - margin; ++i) {
    T* ptr = img.data + i * elemStep;
    for (size_t j = margin; j < img.cols - margin; ++j, ++ptr) {
      T& curr = ptr[margin];
      if (curr != 0) {
        continue;
      }

      T& east  = ptr[margin + 1];
      T& west  = ptr[margin - 1];
      T& north = ptr[margin - elemStep];
      T& south = ptr[margin + elemStep];

      // convert to 0/1 and sum them up
      uchar count = static_cast<bool>(north) + static_cast<bool>(south) +
                    static_cast<bool>(east)  + static_cast<bool>(west);

      // we do not want to divide by 0
      if (count > 0) {
        curr = (north + south + east + west) / count;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three parts: 1) find the zeros, 2) find the mean, and 3) fill the found zeros with mean. So:

```
/****
 * in-place fill zeros with the mean of the surrounding neighborhoods
 ***/
void fillHoles(Mat gray){    
    // find the zeros
    Mat mask = (gray == 0);
    
    // find the mean with filter2d
    Mat kernel = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 
    1/8, 1/8, 1/8
    1/8, 0  , 1/8
    1/8, 1/8, 1/8
    );
    Mat avg;
    cv::filter2d(gray, avg, CV_8U, kernel)
    
    // then fill the zeros, only where indicated by `mask`
    cv::bitwise_or(gray, avg, gray, mask);

}
```

**Note** I just realize that this is plainly taking the average, not the non-zero average. For that operation, you might want to do two filters, one for the sum, one for the non-zero counts, then divide the two:

```
// find the neighborhood sum with filter2d
Mat kernel = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 
1, 1, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 1, 1
);
Mat sums;
cv::filter2d(gray, sums, CV_64F, kernel);

// find the neighborhood count with filter2d
Mat counts;
cv::filter2d(gray!=0, counts, CV_64F, kernel);    
counts /= 255; // because gray!=0 returns 255 where true

// force counts to 1 if 0, so we can divide later
cv::max(counts, 1, counts);

Mat out;
cv::divide(sums, counts, out);

out.convertTo(gray, CV_8U);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please provide explanation for each step? For example, how did you decide/design a 3x3 kernel and so on, please.

Comment: You can read about the kernel here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dbd/tutorial_filter_2d.html

Comment: I just updated the answer with mean of non-zero neighbors. You may want to check for non zero division as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I complied the code with my dummy input matrix. Unfortunately, the output is not matching with my output. Sorry for the inconvenience, but can you please look at it once again? I have added "Update" section on the post as well.